# Por que é que o height não aceita percentagem?

Tags: html, css

Criei este [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w3totvw/) como teste.

Querendo eu ter o ecrã dividido metade verde, metade vermelho, por que é que se na propriedade `height` eu colocar o valor seguido de "%" a `div` desaparece? Estando [aqui](http://prntscr.com/6riugr) a dizer que se pode usar "%".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acredito que isto resolva seu problema. A porcentagem da altura só pode ser obtida se for relativa à outro elementos que contém estas divisões. Você tem que determinar como os blocos superiores devem se comportar em relação à altura.

```css
html, 
body  {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#dv1 {
    width : 100%;
    height : 50%;
    background-color : red;
}

#dv2 {
    width : 100%;
    height : 50%;
    background-color : green;
}
```

```html
<div id="dv1"></div>
<div id="dv2"></div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/StyleBox.html).

Answer (score 6):

Quando você coloca um tamanho em porcentagem, o valor é calculado com base no tamanho do elemento pai. Tendo isso em mente, é interessante notar que por padrão, não existe uma altura definida em um site em branco (ou até com conteúdo). Para ver isso, use o *Inspecionar elemento* e que veja na tag *body* existe uma largura, mas a altura é 0 (ela aumenta de acordo com o conteúdo do site).

Para mudar isso, a técnica é simplesmente definir um valor para o *body* e o *html*:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Após isso, os elementos com tamanho em porcentagem irão ter seus valores calculados corretamente (anteriormente eram calculados com 0).

Answer (score 4):

Height aceita porcentagem sim.

Olha um exemplo:

```css
#tudo {
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
}

.bloco-vermelho {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.bloco-verde {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo">
<div class="bloco-vermelho">
</div>
<div class="bloco-verde">
</div>
  </div>
```

Você pode voltar no seu código e conferir se há ponto e vírgula no final, pois é uma falha comum na hora de aplicar CSS.

Comment: Eu já percebi qual era o problema. O problema era que eu não tinha dado nenhum valor para o html e body, os "pais" da div